SIM card not detected after 6 hours on Samsung Galaxy A15 4G
I’m currently experiencing an issue with my Samsung Galaxy A15 4G. After approximately 6 hours of usage, the phone suddenly behaves as if there’s no SIM card inserted.
I’ve conducted some tests and found that the same issue persists even when the SIM card is placed in the second slot. This has led me to wonder if the problem could be due to the age of my SIM card, which is nearly 8 years old, or if it’s an issue with the phone itself.
Update: I tried a different SIM card and still did the same thing. Also, note that the device is rooted, not sure if that can be something. Also, just testing the phone with none rooted AP file.
Does anyone have any insights on whether the age of a SIM card could cause such an issue? Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

SIM cards also have evolved just like the phones. New models use less voltage and have other advantages. Do yourself a favor and get a new SIM. Most MNOs offer SIM replacements for free.

@Robert oh I didn't think about that tyvm

You should restart the phone to wake up the SIM card.
I have the same problem with my phone (Samsung A24) and the phone is rooted. I have tried everything like resetting the network, factory reset, and flashing a new ROM but still have the same problem every 6 hours.

I was wondering for how long you have had that phone?

One year ago and the phone works fine but when I rooted the phone I lose sim card service after every 6 hours I should restart the phone to make sim works again
